# How do I fill in docker login information in console on Debian OS through a python script

Tags: python, docker, debian

```
import os
os.system("sudo docker login")
//this should be filled in with username first then enter pressed.
//once enter is pressed for the username a password is required which should also be filled in then enter pressed
os.system("sudo docker images")
//to check the images on docker
```

The point of this script is when auto boot through terminal happens on the Debian OS, an already existing username and password should be filled in the required login username and password which would then give access to the docker images so that the user can see them.

I hope i explained it correctly, if you need more clarification please do ask.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you will have to use the Docker SDK for Python. You can install it via pip through:

`pip install docker`

Then you can use the following:

```py
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
client.login(username=your_username, password=your_password)
```